# OSX向けアプリからffmpegが呼び出せない

Tags: macos, unity2d, ffmpeg

Unityで開発を行っております。
OSX向けアプリにffmpegを組み込みたく思い、macPCにffmpegをインストールして、
以下のようなコードを作成いたしました。

```
private IEnumerator ffmpeg( string a_path )
{
 input = "\'"+a_path+"\'";
 output = "\'"+UnityEngine.Application.persistentDataPath + "/work/"+"hoge.mp4"+"\'";

 string ffmpegExePath = "ffmpeg ";
 Process process = new Process();


 string option = "-i";
 option += " "+input;
 option += " -vf";
 option += " scale=480:270";
 option += " -an";
 option += " -preset veryfast";
 option += " -tune film";
 option += " -crf 23";
 option += " -threads 2";
 option += " "+output;

 string l_cmd = ffmpegExePath + option;
 
 process.StartInfo.FileName = "/bin/bash";
 process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-c \" " + l_cmd + " \"";
 process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
 process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
 process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 
 process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
 process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(ProcessErrorDataReceived);
 process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(ProcessOutputDataReceived);
 process.Exited += new EventHandler(ProcessExited);
 
 process.Start();
 process.BeginOutputReadLine();
 process.BeginErrorReadLine();
}
```

しかし、

```
/bin/bash:  ffmpeg -i '/Users/hoge/dev/unity/動画テスト　5%u20106　圧縮.mp4' -vf scale=480:270 -an -preset veryfast -tune film -crf 23 -threads 2 '/Users/hoge/Library/Application Support/HOGE/HOGE App/work/hoge.mp4' : No such file or directory
```

とエラーが返ってまいります。
「ffmpeg -i」からのコマンドをコピペしてターミナルで確認した際はffmpegが起動することを確認しております。

l_cmdを「ffmpeg -version」に変更してバージョンを確認できるか試したところ「/bin/bash: ffmpeg: command not found」と返ってきており、
ffmpegをコマンドとして認識していないのではないかと考えられます。

こちら「ffmpeg」を呼び出すにはどうしたらよろしいのでしょうか。
現在確認はUnityエミュレーター上で行っております。

Unityバージョンは「2020.3.1f1」を使用しております。

よろしくお願い致します。

追記
インストールしたffmpegは呼び出すことができるよになったのでダウンロードしたバイナリファイルをStreamingAssetsフォルダに入れて試したのですがPermission deniedが出て起動できませんでした。
こちら何かご存じでしょうか。

```
string ffmpegExePath = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/KirinUtil/ffmpeg_mac/ffmpeg";
```

と変更して試しました。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: bash経由で実行しているのは何か事情があるのでしょうか?

Comment: 「/bin」に変えて試したところ
Win32Exception: ApplicationName='/bin', CommandLine='-c " usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -version "', CurrentDirectory='', Native error= mono-io-layer-error (2)
とエラーが表示されました。
ffmpegのフルパスで指定したが
Win32Exception: ApplicationName='/bin', CommandLine='-c " ffmpeg -version "', CurrentDirectory='', Native error= mono-io-layer-error (2)
と変わらずエラー表示がされました。

Comment: bash経由しないなら、process.StartInfo.FileName は ffmpeg のフルパス、process.StartInfo.Arguments は変数 option です。 まあ、これで問題が解決するかどうかはわかりませんが。

Comment: 試してみたところ「Win32Exception: ApplicationName='/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg ', CommandLine=' " -i '/Users/hoge/dev/unity/動画テスト　5%u20106　圧縮.mp4' -vf scale=480:270 -an -preset veryfast -tune film -crf 23 -threads 2 '/Users/hoge/Library/Application Support/HOGE/HOGE App/work/hoge.mp4' "', CurrentDirectory='', Native error= mono-io-layer-error (2)」とエラーが返ってまいりました。

Comment: FileNameの末尾に余計なスペースがあります。Arguments全体を " で囲む必要はありません。

Comment: フルパスにすることで呼び出すことに成功しました。そこでダウンロードしたffmpegバイナリから起動かけようとしたのですが、Permission deniedが発生して起動できませんでした。こちら何かご存じでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

```
 string ffmpegExePath = "ffmpeg ";
```

の`ffmpeg`を`which`等で取得できるフルパスに書き替えてみてはいかがでしょうか？
（どうやってインストールしたのか解りませんが、例えば
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
等です。

Comment: whichで取得したファイルパスに書き換えて試してみましたが、「No such file or directory」とエラーが返ってまいりました。

Comment: 質問のコメントを見ると "usr/localbin/ffmpeg"とされたようですが、"/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg"の間違いでは？

Comment: もしくは、process.StartInfo.FileName = "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg"なのではないでしょうか？

Comment: usr/local/bin/ffmpegで試しております。

Comment: 先頭に/がある絶対パスと/がない相対パスは別物です。"/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg"とすべきだとおもいます

Comment: 先頭に/を付けることで呼び出すことに成功しました。そこでダウンロードしたffmpegバイナリから起動かけようとしたのですが、Permission deniedが発生して起動できませんでした。こちら何かご存じでしょうか。

Comment: あまりにアバウトすぎてなにを聞きたいのか解りません。別質問を立てて何をどうしてどうやったらどうなったかをちゃんと他の人が再現出来るように説明した質問をお願いします

Comment: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/75274/%e3%83%80%e3%82%a6%e3%83%b3%e3%83%ad%e3%83%bc%e3%83%89%e3%81%97%e3%81%9fffmpeg%e3%83%90%e3%82%a4%e3%83%8a%e3%83%aa%e3%82%92%e5%91%bc%e3%81%b3%e5%87%ba%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e9%9a%9b%e3%81%abpermission-denied%e3%81%8c%e3%81%a7%e3%81%a6%e8%b5%b7%e5%8b%95%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e3%81%93%e3%81%a8%e3%81%8c%e3%81%a7%e3%81%8d%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84
に新しく質問を建てました。よろしくお願い致します。